# add class in for loop button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
(function ($) {
$.fn.fCycle = function () {
        var x;
        for (x in arguments) {
            $(arguments[x]).close();
        }
        $(this).collapse("show");
    };

$(".btn-next").on('click', function() {
        var form = [$("#name"), $("#surname"), $("#student_number"), $("#cellphone"), $("#email"), $("#course"), $("#year")],
            i = 0,
            a = "#" + $(this).attr("data-to"),
            b = "#" + $(this).attr("data-from");
        if ($(this).hasClass("to_course")) {
            for (i; i < 5; i++) {
                console.log(form[i].val());
                if (form[i].val() === undefined) {
                    form[i].addClass("has-danger")
                    $(a).fCycle(b);
                } else if (form[i].hasClass("has-danger") && form[i].length > 0) {
                    form[i].removeClass("has-danger")
                }
            }
            $(a).fCycle(b);
        }
    });
  }(jquery));
$(".btn-next").on('click', function () {
 var form = [$("#name")],
     i = 0,
        a = "#" + $(this).attr("data-to"),
        b = "#" + $(this).attr("data-from");
    if ($(this).hasClass("to_course")) {
        for (i; i < form.length; i++) {
            if (form[i].val() === undefined) {
                form[i].addClass("has-danger")
                $(a).fCycle(b);
            } 
   else if (form[i].hasClass("has-danger") && form[i].length > 0) {
                form[i].removeClass("has-danger");
            }
        }
        $(a).fCycle(b);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="post" id="apply">
        <div id="personal" class="collapse in">
            <fieldset class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="names">Name(s)</label> 
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="names" id="names" placeholder="Enter your full name here">
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="pager">
                            <li>
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-cancel" type="button">cancel</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="pager-next">
                                <button class="btn btn-next btn-success to_course" type="button" data-to="course" data-from="personal">next</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div id="course" class="collapse">
            <p>course</p>
        </div>
    </form>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above snippet doesn't seem to work at all - in the case of the Original (http://alpha.msauwc.co.za -> if you click on the `Join the MSA` button,
You'll find that the form does work. The issue is that the `next` button should not be working when the input fields have not been filled.

This has to be prevented using jquery.

Comment: Please post HTML snippet

Comment: Depends on the types of the form elements, but for example the value of `input type="text"` is never `undefined`. If there's no text entered, the value is an empty string. This means that the first `if` in the loop will never pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your array with just selector strings, and then wrapping your `form[i]` objects like:

`$(form[i]).val()`, `$(form[i]).addClass('has-danger')`, etc

Comment: first off, there is a js error because the jquery lib is loaded after the bootstrap so, those script include definitions will have to be switched. second, you will need to add `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.1.1/css/tether.min.css` to the head, and `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.1.1/js/tether.min.js` to the script includes, in between the jquery and bootstrap includes.

Comment: I don't know why, but after messing around with it - it started working again, This seems to have been the correct direction to go, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these methods to disable & activate the button:

```
$(".btn-next").addClass('disabled') // when you want to disable it
$(".btn-next").removeClass('disabled') // when you want to activate it
```